# Example of Field Extension $E/F$ with $Char(F)=2$ and $[E:F]=2$, but is not Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I understand that for a field extension $E/F$, if $Char(F)\neq 2$ and $[E:F]=2$ then it must be a Galois Extension. I have proved this, but I am having trouble finding a counterexample when the characteristic requirement is dropped.

My first thought was something like $\mathbb{F}_{2}(\sqrt{t})/\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$.

I am not sure, however, if this is a degree 2 extension.

Regardless, the minimum irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt{t}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$ is $f(x) = x^{2}-t = 0$. Clearly, $(f,f')=f\neq1$ and, in $\mathbb{F}_{2}(\sqrt{t})$, $f$ splits into $(x-\sqrt{t})^{2}$, so it is purely inseparable.

Is this enough to show that $\mathbb{F}_{2}(\sqrt{t})/\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$ is an inseparable extension? And is it indeed degree 2?

Answer (score 3):

Another way, equivalent to yours, let's determine $Aut$($F_{2}$($\sqrt{t})/F_{2}(t))$. As you suggested, $\sqrt{t}$ is the only root of $x^{2}-t \in F_{2}(t)[x]$ and hence $Aut$($F_{2}$($\sqrt{t})/F_{2}(t))$=$\lbrace$ identity $\rbrace$<2.

Comment: Ah and if E/F is Galois then the order of Gal(E/F) must equal the degree of E/F?

Comment: Jup, well you can't really say Gal(E/F), but Aut(E/F).

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess this notation is uncommon, but it is used by Rotman in his Galois Theory textbook.

Comment: Oh, it's just a notation matter (Gal(E/F) is Aut(E/F) when E/F is Galois)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There is no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, nice counterexample.

The degree of the extension $\Bbb F_2(\sqrt t):\Bbb F_2(t)$ is indeed $2$, because -- as you wrote -- the minimum irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt t$ over $\Bbb F_2(t)$ is $f(x)=x^2-t$, which has degree $2$.

Comment: Of course. I was trying to think about vector spaces and was unsure if ${1,\sqrt{t}}$ was a basis, but clearly the degree of the minimum irred. polynomial is all that is needed.